# Weird truncated margin on the Homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

[image]

The left margin on the homepage  seems truncated, is it just me ?

Tested on:
Firefox 3.6.3 - Windows 2003 server

Comment: How can the operating system be relevant? The page should be rendered by the browser's rendering engine, regardless of how old your OS is.

Comment: I meant to set the voting box bg to transparent, not white. The fix will be in the next deployment...

Comment: @jin ah, ok :) I thought it was just me.

Comment: you bit me to it.... was going to post about it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed the fix to dev. The change will be on live in the next deployment.

Comment: Is there a way to see dev?