# Bug? SO Home Page Votes Background Color Just became White on Yellow

Tags: bug, questions, tag-watching, homepage, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird truncated margin on the Homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82273/weird-truncated-margin-on-the-homepage)

This looks a little broken. Just happened within the last few hours. Used to be that the votes box was grey. Right now it looks kinda broken. Perhaps allow the yellow to surround around the left or put it back to grey.

[image]

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate or at least related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82301/sos-vote-box-seems-to-look-different

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82273/weird-truncated-margin-on-the-homepage